# Formula to check if rows that have the same value in one column have matching values in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

To elaborate; I have an excel with ~4k lines. Lets say column B has numbers. Multiple rows will have the same number in that column (usually like 2-6 will match). Column C has words that will sometimes match with other cells in the same column of the rows that had matching values in column B.

So I want to create a formula that, for each each "chunk" of rows with matching values in column B, will look to see if that chunk also has matching values in column C (but only for that specific group of rows of matching B columns).

[image: Example Excel]

Basically I'm trying to narrow down this list and get rid of a big chunk of manual work since if they match I'm not worried about them so I was thinking of just making an `=IF(Test, "Y","N")` and putting that in a column and deleting all the Y's after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will count the matching column B & column C values.  Then eliminate all rows with result greater than 1 to find unique values.

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,B1,C:C,C1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great and gave me the method I needed to further narrow down my list. Much appreciated.